# Align xticklabels in bar plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a bar plot in matplotlib. My plot is more complex, but the main problem is with aligning of xlabels.

What I have right now is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
random.seed(0)

counts = [random.randint(10000000000, 20000000000) for i in xrange(15)]
x_labels = ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) # I actually have many subplots, but this is not related to a problem
ax.bar(range(len(counts)), [v / 1000. for v in counts], align='center')
ax.set_title('some title')
ax.set_ylabel('some y label')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation='vertical', ha='center')
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.get_figure().tight_layout()
ax.get_figure().subplots_adjust(top=0.97)

plt.show()
```

which produces 15 bars:

[image]

A problem is that I want my labels ('10', '11', ..., '24') right below each of the bars (15 bars, 15 labels). But for some reason I have my label '10' somewhere on the left, my label '11' below the first bar and labels about '20' are not even seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the position where each one goes (the same one you use for the bars):

```
ax.set_xticks(range(len(counts)))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, just one line. And I spent like 40 minutes on this stuff. Thank you.